# How to mount server to other computers?

Tags: networking, server, backup, rsync

Any idea what's the best way to set up my server for file sharing and backup?

I have to tower PCs now. My main computer has Ubuntu 20.04 installed. As well as multiple boot drives with Windows 10 (for gaming) and MacOS Catalina (as a hackintsih for XCode projects). My second computer is my old gaming computer chillin' under my desk. It has Ubuntu Server installed. I've managed to mount all my older spinning hard drives to it. And got them all to mount at boot using chrontab.

What I want to do is set it up as a back up system. I want to use something like Arq or RSync to backup all my drives to it (and eventually create a raid array for it.)

What's the best protocol to use to mount the drives from my other computers in a way that back-up softwear can easily see them?

Comment: Mostly just for ease of use. Windows doesn't have rsync so I'll need to use something else. I might use Time Machine for mac instead of rsync so I can use Migration assistant later. Also the ability to access the files from my iPhone in the files app.

Basically "Make this network drive look like a local drive" is easier to work with for certain situations.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1247620/edit) to clarify that you want to back up *from those multiple operating systems* instead of that you want to simply back up disks with different formats.